# Raspberry Pi 4B 8 GB not booting and the green light flashes briefly when powered and goes blank

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

So I recently purchased a new Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB from an official store, and it worked well without any problems. After 2 weeks, the Pi stopped booting altogether. Whenever I plug it in, the green light blinks for a fraction of a second, then goes blank. The red light is always on (so the Pi is receiving power). I have tried using multiple power supplies, reformatting and imaging the SD card, trying a different SD card, trying a USB drive instead of an SD card, and cleaning all the ports but it is not giving any signal to the HDMI slot or Display connectors, and I don't think the SD card slot and USBs are even receiving any voltage. The RAM and CPU are not warming up even a little so I think that power is not getting past the power circuitry (the voltage regulators, power dividers etc.) I haven't done any tests with my multimeter because I don't know what to look for. After doing some research I heard that it could be due to a short circuit but I don't know where that could be. I have noticed that if I touch a certain component on the Raspberry Pi, the green light is turning on, but it still isn't working (the USBs aren't receiving power and I am not getting any HDMI signals), while I touch the component. I think it may have something to do with a short circuit or component failure, or grounding, but I am not completely sure.

Sorry for the bad English, if you do not understand something or need some clarification, please leave a comment.

[image: Image of the component that makes the green LED light up when I touch it.]

Comment: I have seen lots of posts with this same problem, but none of them have answers that seem to work on my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

From the information given, there could be a few possible issues with your Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB. Here are some steps you can take to diagnose the issue:

- SD Card Issues: First, I would suggest verifying the SD card. Sometimes, Raspberry Pi booting issues are caused by problems with the SD card. You've mentioned that you've tried different SD cards and reformatted them, but it's crucial to ensure that the SD card is properly flashed with the Raspberry Pi OS.
- Power Supply: It's important to ensure that the power supply is adequate. Raspberry Pi requires a 5V power supply with sufficient current (around 2.5A), as insufficient power can cause booting issues as well.
- It is also worth checking your HDMI cable and screen are functioning perfectly by testing it with another device.
- Test Points: You mentioned you have a multimeter. You could check test points on the Raspberry Pi, paying attention to TP1 and TP2 (5V power rail), TP3 and TP4 (3V3 power rail), and TP5 and TP6 (ground). They should read 5 volts when not in use.
- Hardware Failure: Finally, it's possible the Raspberry Pi itself could have a hardware issue. You mentioned touching a component triggers the green light, which indicates the issue could possibly be a short circuit, improper grounding or an outright component failure. If the Pi is still under warranty I would recommend to return or exchange it.

Comment: Is this a generic AI response?

Comment: Its a generic question, I covered all of the possibilities i could think of

Comment: @Rapidmod The SD card is correctly imaged and works on other Raspberry Pis, The power supply is new and works on other Raspberry PIs. Everything was working fine until I shut down the Pi. The next time I turned it on, this problem appeared. I think that this is a problem with the power circuitry (the voltage regulators, power dividers etc.) I will consider returning it. My HDMI cable is fine, I ran a few continuity tests on it and it works on another device. The Pi is getting power but is not doing anything with it. It wont boot.